# Expand on this autoboxing explanation

Tags: java, boxing, autoboxing

I asked:

> Is autoboxing/unboxing is done at runtime (JVM) or compile time (compiler)?

I received this answer:

> Autoboxing is achieved by the insertion of method calls and casts by the compiler, into the code. These calls and casts are handled at runtime.

Please explain in more detail.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: I would explain in more detail, but I don't understand which part is not clear to you. Do you know what autoboxing is?

Answer (score 3):

From Java Specification

[Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

> Every expression written in the Java programming language has a type
>   that can be deduced from the structure of the expression and the types
>   of the literals, variables, and methods mentioned in the expression.
>   It is possible, however, to write an expression in a context where the
>   type of the expression is not appropriate. In some cases, this leads
>   to an error at compile time. In other cases, the context may be able
>   to accept a type that is related to the type of the expression; **as a
>   convenience, rather than requiring the programmer to indicate a type
>   conversion explicitly, the Java programming language performs an
>   implicit conversion from the type of the expression to a type
>   acceptable for its surrounding context**.

From here, we know compiler will accept particular expression even if the programmer does not indicate a type conversion. That's why following code does not raise an error at compile time.

```
int i = new Integer(3);
Integer j = 3;
```

[Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions 5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> ... At run time, boxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> If p is a value of type boolean, then boxing conversion converts p
>   into a reference r of class and type Boolean, such that
>   r.booleanValue() == p ...

[Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions 5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)

> ... At run-time, unboxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> If r is a reference of type Boolean, then unboxing conversion converts
>   r into r.booleanValue() ...

and this is what happens exactly in run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Autoboxing and unboxing are compile time processes.

We can verify with a small test as described below:

Create a Java project, say, with name 'Crap'. Inside that, create a .java file with below contents:

```
public class Crap {

    private Boolean crap;

    public Boolean getCrap() {
        return crap;
    }

    public void setCrap(Boolean crap) {
        System.out.println("lol.. this is crap!!");
        this.crap = crap;
    }
}
```

Build this project and export as a jar file, say crap.jar.

Now create one more Java project, say, with name 'Junk'. Add crap.jar file into the classpath of this project and then create a .java file with below contents:

```
public class Junk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Crap crap = new Crap();
        crap.setCrap(true);
    }
}
```

Now, build Junk project, and run Junk.java as Java application. It will run successfully and the output will be

lol.. this is crap!!

Now, modify Crap.java, modify the Boolean crap to boolean and also the corresponding getters and setters. Code will look like as below:

```
public class Crap {

    private boolean crap;

    public boolean getCrap() {
        return crap;
    }

    public void setCrap(boolean crap) {
        System.out.println("lol.. this is crap!!");
        this.crap = crap;
    }
}
```

Again build this project and export it as crap.jar. Put this crap.jar file into the classpath of Junk project (and remove the earlier jar file from its classpath).

Now if you try to run Junk.java as java application, you will get below stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: crap.Crap.setCrap(Ljava/lang/Boolean;) at junk.Junk.main(Junk.java:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it says the compiler does it. So it happens at compile time.

This is necessary to ensure the static type safety of Java.

Answer (score 0):

In [Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), it says:

> ```
> List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
> for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 2)
>     li.add(i);
> ```
>
> ... The compiler does not generate an error because it creates an `Integer` object from `i` and adds the object to `li`. Thus, the compiler converts the previous code to the following at runtime:
>
> ```
> List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
> for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 2)
>     li.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
> ```

So the conversions, which are achieved by the insertion of method calls and casts (by the compiler) into the code, occur at compile time but are processed at runtime.